# Why i am getting a 422 - Unprocessable Entity Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, ruby, error-handling, mern

I am working on a pinterest clone and I am having some trouble when i try to create a new pin. I get Completed 422 Unprocessable Entity in 3ms (Views: 0.1ms | ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
I am not sure what else to try. AT first i thought it was my authenticity token and i tried protect_from_forgery unless: -> { request.format.json? } but still doesn't work.
Any suggestions???

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

   root to: 'static_pages#root'
 
   namespace :api, defaults: { format: :json } do 
    resources :users, only: [:show,:new, :create, :index]
    resource :session, only: [:new, :create, :destroy, :show]
    resources :pins, only: [:create, :show, :index, :edit, :destroy]
     resources :boards, only: [:create, :show, :edit, :destroy]
  end
  
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 
  attr_reader :password
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true
  validates :password_digest, :session_token, presence: true
  validates :password, length: { minimum: 6 }, allow_nil: true
  
  after_initialize :ensure_session_token

  has_many :pins,
  foreign_key: :author_id, 
  class_name: :Pin

  has_many :boards,
  foreign_key: :author_id, 
  class_name: :Board

  has_many :pins_in_boards,
    through: :boards,
    source: :boards_pins
 
  
  def self.find_by_credentials(username, password)
    user = User.find_by(username: username)
    return nil unless user
    user.is_password?(password) ? user : nil
  end
  def password=(password)
    @password = password
    self.password_digest = BCrypt::Password.create(password)
  end
  
  def is_password?(password)
    BCrypt::Password.new(self.password_digest).is_password?(password)
  end

  def ensure_session_token
    self.session_token ||= SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
  end
  def reset_session_token!
    self.session_token = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    self.save
    self.session_token
  end
end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class Api::UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
     @user = User.find_by(username: params[:id])
      if @user
        render :show
      else
        render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: 404
      end
  end
  def new
    @user = User.new
    render :new
  end
  
  def index
    @users =User.all
    render :index
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    if @user.save
      sign_in(@user)
       render "api/users/show"
    else
      render json: @user.errors.full_messages, status: 422
    end
  end

  private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:password, :username)
  end
end
```

pins_controller.rb

```
class Api::PinsController < ApplicationController
   
   
  def index
     @pins = user.pins
  end
  
   def new
      @pin = Pin.new(user_id: current_user.id)
      render :new
    end

  def show
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    render :show
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.new(pin_params)
     
    if @pin.save
      render :show
    else
      render json: @pin.errors.full_messages, status: 422
    end
  end

  def edit
    @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    unless @pin.author_id == current_user.id
      render "api/pins/show"
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    pin = current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    pin.destroy
  end

  private
  def pin_params
    params.require(:pin).permit(
      :title, 
      :description, 
      :url, 
      :author_id,
      :photo
    )

  end


    def user
        @user ||= User.find(params[:user_id])
    end
     def pin
        @pin ||= current_user.pins.find(params[:id])
    end


end
```

pin.rb

```
class Pin < ApplicationRecord
    validates :title, :description, :author_id, presence: true

    belongs_to :user

    belongs_to :board
    has_many :boards
    has_one_attached :photo

   

    has_many :users,
        through: :boards,
        source: :author


end
```

creat_pin_form_container.jsx

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import PinForm from './pin_form';
import { createPin } from '../../actions/pins_actions';
import { openModalForm, closeModalForm } from '../../actions/modal_form_actions';


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    pin: {
        title: '',
        description: '',
        photoFile: null
    },
    
    formType: 'New Pin'
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    action: pin => dispatch(createPin(pin)),
     closeModalForm: () => dispatch(closeModalForm())
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(PinForm);
```

pin_form.jsx

```
import React from 'react';

class PinForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = this.props.pin;

        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleFile = this.handleFile.bind(this);
    }

    handleSubmit(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('pin[title]', this.state.title);
        formData.append('pin[description]', this.state.description);
        formData.append('pin[url]', this.state.url);
        formData.append('pin[photo]', this.state.photoFile);
        this.props.action(formData, this.state.id);
    }

    update(field) {
        return e => this.setState({ [field]: e.currentTarget.value });
    }

    handleFile(e){
        this.setState({ photoFile: e.currentTarget.files[0] })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="pin-form-container"> 
                <form  onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="create-edit-form-top">
                        <nav className="pin-form-header">
                           
                            <div onClick={this.props.closeModalForm} className="close-pin"><img src={window.cancelURL} /></div>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                    <div className="new-pin"> <h3>{this.props.formType}</h3></div>
                    <div className="create-edit-form-left">
                        <label className="photo-upload">
                            <img src={this.state.photoUrl} /> 
                    <input
                        type="file"
                        onChange={this.handleFile}
                        />
                    </label>
                    </div>
                    <div className="create-edit-form-right">
                       
                    <label className="create-edit-form-title">
                        <input
                            type='text'
                            value={this.state.title}
                            placeholder="Add your title"
                            onChange={this.update('title')}
                        />
                    </label>
                    <label className="create-edit-form-description">
                        <textarea
                            cols="30"
                            rows="1"
                            value={this.state.description}
                            placeholder="Tell everyone what your Pin is about"
                            onChange={this.update('description')}
                        />
                    </label>
                        <label className="add-url">
                            <input
                                type='text'
                                placeholder="Add a destination link"
                                onChange={this.update('url')}
                            />
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <button className="pin-submit" type='submit'>Save</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default PinForm;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
protect_from_forgery with: :null_session
```

Comment: It would be good if you provide an explanation about the command so it is clear how and why it may solve the problem.